# PHPUnit strict mode and non-public methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm using strict mode with `@covers ::<!public>` annotation on test case level to cover all protected/private methods, so I can ignore implementation details and don't hardcode `@covers` for non-public methods in tests.

Is there any reason against this approach?

Comment: Unless you're not covering public methods, why don't you use a class level @covers?

Comment: I am, strict mode enforces `checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode` which also includes non-public methods. If public method you cover in the test calls non-public method in the same class it's marked as uncovered.